# Format Timestamp X Axis Chart to 24 hours only

Tags: javascript, extjs, charts, sencha-touch, axis

I'm creating a line chart using ExtJs, and I would like to have 24 hour x-axis. However, I found an issue with duplicate x hours. I set formatter to show only 24 hours(`groupBy: 'h'`) like this:

```
           {
                type: 'time',
                dateFormat: 'h',
                groupBy: 'h',
                fields: ['timestamp'],
                position: 'bottom',
                label: {
                    rotate: {
                        degrees: -45
                    }
                }
```

Here is my live example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ulv

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed: (UNIX timestamp from OVH API was divided per 1000.)

```
dateFormat : "U"
```